# find residue modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Find the residue , modulo $317$, of $5^{17}$. Hence calculate the residue, modulo $317$ of $401 (5^{17})$.

Really struggling with this question I have attempted the first part as follows
\begin{align}5^1 & = 5 & \\
    5^2 & = 25 & \pmod{317}\\
    5^4 & = 25^2 = 308 & \pmod{317}\\
    5^8 & = 308^2 = 81 & \pmod{317}\\
    5^{16} & = 81^2 = 221 & \pmod{317}\\
    5\cdot 221 & = 154 & \pmod{317}\end{align}

I think this is correct but do not know how to begin the second part ? Hence calculate the residue, modulo $317$ of $401(5^{17})$. Is it just

$$401 \cdot 154 \pmod{317}?$$

Comment: The $154$ is correct.  The other isn't any harder to do from scratch, but I don't see any way to instantly deduce it from the first.  Are you sure the modulus changed?

Comment: Given that the modulus should stay $317$, you now have $401\times 5^{17}\equiv 84\times 154\pmod {317}$ which is easy enough to do by hand (helps if you note that $2\times 154=308\equiv -9$).